# Web Service intermediaries

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, soap, soa

My requirement is, Web Service client will invoke a request and the ultimate  end point of the request is , let us say D, which should traverse through multiple intermediates endpoints , let us A,B,C.

Web Service Client --> A --> B ---> C ---> D.

Also each intermediates should process some of the message and the output should be updated in the message part before forwarding to next node (Consider encrypted using the specific keys).

If there is any error, it should traverse back to client.

I read so many article about soap intermediates and actor, but couldnt understand it clearly.

Can any of you explain how we can achieve this in web service?

Regards
Udhaya